# show that if $f: \Bbb R^k \rightarrow \Bbb R$ when $ k \geq 2 $ is partial continuous function, than its not injective

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I told on a different question that I study calculus 3, and the teacher likes to give us difficult questions. here's one of them: "let $ k \geq 2 $, let $f :\Bbb R^k \rightarrow \Bbb R $ be a partial function who is continuous in a punctured neighborhood of a point $ a \in \Bbb R^k $. prove that f is not injective". as a clue, he wrote "in every punctured neighborhood there exists a loop. if the function is injective, you will get a contradiction to the intermediate value theorem on one part of the loop". I don't really know how this is helping me in any way. maybe I'm missing something which is obvious? I could really use some help here.

Comment: What is partial function? Is it the partial derivatives?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function

Comment: Have you tried drawing pictures? With that hint, drawing pictures of the restriction of a function to a loop may be quite helpful.

Comment: @macton. A partial function on S is a function whose domain is a subset of S.  On the Q the key is that dom(f) has non-empty interior.

Answer (score 1):

There is a circle $C\subset dom(f).$ That is, there is a continuous surjection $g:[0,2\pi]\to C$ such that $g(0)=g(2\pi)$ and the restriction of $g$ to the domain $[0,2\pi)$ is injective.

For $x\in [0,2\pi]$ let $h(x)=f(g(x)).$ We have $h(0)=h(2\pi).$ Now if $f$ is continuous then so is $h$.

Exercise: Prove that if $h:[0,2\pi]\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and $h(0)=h(2\pi)$ then there exist $x_1,x_2$ with $0<x_1<x_2<2\pi$ and $h(x_1)= h(x_2).$

Hence if $f$ is continuous then $h$ cannot be injective on the domain $[0,2\pi).$ But $g$ $is$ injective on $[0,2\pi),$ so a continuous $f$ cannot be injective on $C.$

Proof of Exercise: There exists $x_1\in (0,\pi)$ with $h(x_1)=\frac {h(0)+h(\pi)}{2}$ and there exists $x_2\in (\pi,2\pi)$ with $h(x_2)=\frac {h(2\pi)+h(\pi)}{2}=\frac {h(0)+h(\pi)}{2}=h(x_1).$

Comment: There are many many ways to show that if $k\ge 2 $ then a subset of $\Bbb R^k$ with non-empty interior cannot be mapped by a continuous injection into $\Bbb R$ but I had not thought of this simple  method before.  Good hint by your teacher.

Comment: Why is your loop between $0$ and $2\pi $ ?

Comment: @Tomer You want to think of $g$ as a parameterization of the circle. For example, if $k=2$ and $a=(0,0)$ (which we can assume WLOG), then we can find a $\delta >0$ so that the image of $g:[0,2\pi]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $$g(x)=\big(\delta \cos(x),\delta \sin(x)\big)$$ is contained in the punctured neighborhood of the origin.